# How can I get an output from inserting data using a from

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

I tried to insert data using the following code, but I really I don't know how can I get result and what is the problem in my code, I tried to build firstly my form then I write the insert query and send it to a new form , any HELP please : 
Also I Have now the following error:

---

Notice: Undefined index: Services in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: RootCause in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: RiskRating in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: impact in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: Efforts in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: likelihood in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: Finding in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: Implication in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: Recommendation in C:\xampp\htdocs\ers\test.php on line 20
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ers_1`.`findings`, CONSTRAINT `findings_ibfk_15` FOREIGN KEY (`ServiceType_ID`) REFERENCES `servicetype_lookup` (`ServiceType_ID`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

---

```
 <html>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
error_reporting(0); 
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

?>

<form method="post"  action="test.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Insert New Data </legend>
<p> Service Name : 
<select name="Services">
<option value="select"> -Select- </option>
<option value="architecture review">Architecture Review</option>
<option value="internal penetration testing">Internal Penetration Testing</option>
<option value="network component review">Network Component Review</option>
<option value="database review">Database Review</option>
<option value="wireless network">Wireless Network</option>
<option value="operating system review">Operating System Review</option>
<option value="web application">Web Application</option>
<option value="external penetration testing">External Penetration Testing</option>
</select>

</p>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
Ref : <input type="text" name="ref" /><br />
Title : <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
Risk Rating : 
<select name="RiskRating">
<option value="select"> -Select- </option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Low">Low</option>
</select><br />
Root Cause : 
<select name="RootCause">
<option value="select"> -Select- </option>
<option value="access control">Access Control</option>
<option value="configuration management">Configuration Management</option>
<option value="patch management">Patch Management</option>
<option value="patch management">Certificate Management</option>

<option value="patch management">Password Management</option>

<option value="patch management">Audit Trail and Security Logs Management</option>

<option value="service deployment">Network Management</option>
</select><br />
Impact :
<select name="impact">
<option value="select"> -Select- </option>
<option value="high"> Major </option>
<option value="moderate"> Moderate </option>
<option value="low"> Minor </option>
</select><br />
Likelihood :
<select name="likelihood">
<option value="select"> -Select- </option>
<option value="possible"> Likely </option>
<option value="impossible">Possible</option>
<option value="definite"> Moderate </option>
<option value="definite"> Rare </option>
</select><br/>
Efforts : 
<select name="Efforts">
<option value="select"> -Select- </option>
<option value="possible"> Significant </option>
<option value="impossible">Moderate </option>
<option value="definite"> Intermediate </option>
<option value="definite"> Simple </option>
</select><br/>
Finding : <br/>
<TEXTAREA NAME="Finding" COLS=100 ROWS=10> 
</TEXTAREA>
<br/>
Implication: <br/>
<TEXTAREA NAME="Implication" COLS=100 ROWS=10> 
</TEXTAREA>
<br/>
Recommendation : <br/>
<TEXTAREA NAME="Recommendation" COLS=100 ROWS=10> 

</TEXTAREA>
<br/><input type="submit" value=" Save " onclick="window.location.href='test.php'" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
mysql_select_db("ers_1", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM findings");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Finding_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ServiceType_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['RootCause_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['RiskRating_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Impact_ID'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Efforts_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Likelihood_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Finding'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Implication'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['Recommendation'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Report_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='edit.php'>[EDIT]</a> <a href='delete_risk.php?risk_no=" . $row['risk_no'] . "'>[DELETE]</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to ask? use your words

Comment: where is the mysql_query($sql) for insert statement

Comment: I wrote it "$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM findings");"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: RJ45, I don't get the inserted data

Comment: vascowhite, Thanks I will read it now ..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the entire setup is a pretty large mess.

One large problem is this line:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO findings ... ";
```

You defined a string that would take all of the values from the form, but you don't do anything with it.

To run an SQL query, you use `mysql_query()`.

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

However, I would recommend reading up on the basics of PHP/MySQL so you understand the code you're writing. It looks like you're sticking things together, hoping it works.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

I think You used two forms and even you used one form in another form like:

```
<form id="form1">
    //Some code
<form id="form2">
    //More some
</form>
```

It is never possible to use nested forms.That's it.if you use two forms then better to avoid nested forms and also give individual triggers for both.